# sql 2000 + vs 2008, debugging through sproc?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures

Hey all.  Is it possible to step through a sproc on sql server 2000 server using vs 2008?

When I go through the server explorer and choose to step into the sproc, it asks me to enter the param values and then it gives me the output of the sproc, without stepping into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps sound correct for SQL Server 2005/2008. Having said that, I know for SQL Server 2000, it's possible to enumerate the sprocs via Query Analyzer, right click, and then debug from there. Not sure if that's acceptable or not in your current environment, but that should do the trick if using server explorer doesn't pan out.

(Note that this is all from memory, since I don't have SQL Server 2000 installed on my dev box anymore.)